# Using decimal character as ',' in jquery calculator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

The problem raise when we add decimal character ',' in jquery calculator plugin and try to add it using physical keyboard.

The following code is of the plugin from the github itself

## jquery.calculator.js

```
_doKeyPress: function(e) {
  ........
  if (plugin._showingCalculator || (div && !plugin.isDisabled(div))) {
    var code = plugin._keyChars[ch === inst.options.decimalChar ? '.' : ch];
    if (code) {
      $('button[data-keystroke="' + code + '"]', inst._mainDiv).not(':disabled').click();
    }
  return false;
  }
  ........
},
```

My question is, can we do anything other then modify code here only?

Comment: Can you set inst.options.decimalChar?

Comment: It's already set, i.e. when we define decimalChar while defining calculator. Let say in this case, it is ',' but the third party code is replacing that with '.'

Comment: So, when  next line will search the '.' key to press, but as per specification there is no '.' key on keyboard but there will be ',' key.

Comment: @AnkurMishra The third party code doesn't appear to replace the `inst.options.decimalChar`, it's checking whether it's set and falling back to `'.'`. Can you show us your code where you set the options?

Comment: $.extend( config , {
  layout : ['_%BSCECA' ,
  '_1_2_3_+@X' ,
  '_4_5_6_-@U' ,
  '_7_8_9_*@E' ,
  'dc_0_=_/']
} );

Comment: el.calculator( {
  buttonImage        : "images/janna/icon_calculator_sm.gif" ,
  buttonImageOnly : true ,
  layout                   : config.layout ,
  onOpen               : config.beforeShow ,
  onClose               : config.close ,
  decimalChar        : dc
} );

Comment: dc is decimal character which is either '.' or ','